# Roundcube mail AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Temporary authentication failure

Tags: dovecot, roundcube

I set up a Roundcube mail server on an Ubuntu vm (AWS). For user logins I made a mysql database called roundcube which contains usernames and passwords. It's using dovecot and IMAP. When I open the mail server in my browser and attempt to login I get error:
IMAP Error in /var/www/html/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php (196): Login failed  AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Temporary authentication failure.

and under the login fields on the browser it says login failed.

When I run telnet mail.domain.com 993
Trying (ip address)...
Connected to mail.domain.com.

telnet mail.domain.com 143
Connected

ping mail.domain.ca results in  4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3030ms

tail -1 /var/www/html/roundcube/logs/errors
IMAP Error: Login failed for testuser from (my ip). AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Temporary authentication failure. in /var/www/html/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 196 (POST /?_task=login&_action=login)

my roundcube config.inc.php contains:

```
$config = array();

$config['debug'] = true;
$config['debug_level'] = 13;

$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.mail.mydomain.com';
$username = '***';
$password = '***';
$config['db_dsnw'] = sprintf('mysql://%s:%s@localhost/roundcube', $username, $password);

$config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'PLAIN';
$config['imap_auth_type'] = 'PLAIN';


$config['sql_table'] = array(
    'users' => 'users',
    'password_col' => 'password_plain',
    'username_col' => 'username',
);
$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://mail.mydomain.com';
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://mail.mydomain.com';
$config['default_port'] = 993;
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
$config['product_name'] = 'Roundcube Webmail';

$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'       => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$config['imap_conn_options'] = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'       => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

In my sshed Ubuntu terminal I ran:
curl -d "task=login" -d "_task=login" -d "_action=login" -d "_timezone=" -d "_url=" -d
"_user=username" -d "_pass=password" "https://mail.mydomain.ca/?_task=login"
and it looks like login is successful

Any help would be appreciated. Trying to get login on the browser page working and then setting up inboxes for the users in the mysql database to receive emails.